# What makes a "Top Network Asker"?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, asking-questions

On [Stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/), in the side bar is a list of the "Top Network Askers", having just found this I thought it would be showing off the most prolific and highest rep earning users ever to ask questions on Stack Exchange but this does not seem to be the case.

The first user I clicked on was a new account, from today, with a single question, hardly a "Top Network Asker" by anyone's definition of the phrase.

Further investigation shows a whole mess of users with all kinds of different statistics based on their questions, some are higher rep, with many questions, others like the one I previously mentioned and everything in-between, so now I am confused about what actually makes a "Top Network Asker".

What is the criteria for someone to appear on this list?

If it doesn't actually show the top askers on the network, shouldn't the title be changed to reflect what the list actually shows?

Comment: The linked question tells you what the Top Network Askers are, and raises similar doubts about the usefulness of the list.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks, I see now.